# Logical inconsistency with Optionals

Tags: swift, option-type

Apple claims that this expression evaluates to two things

```
let x= fubar?.boo
```

If `fubar` exists, it unwraps `fubar` and fetches `boo` which let’s say is a real object not an optional. If `fubar` doesn’t exist, you get `nil`. However `x` is not declared as optional itself, so in one case `x` will be either optional or not and this is determined at runtime. This seems like a terrible design.

Comment: `Apple claims that this expression evaluates to two things` — citation needed

Comment: *so in one case x will be either optional or not and this is determined at runtime* - no, Swift types are always determined at compile time.  In Xcode, you can option click on x to see its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. The compiler infers the type of `x` and due to the optional chaining used, it will infer the type of `x` to be `Optional`.

The type of `x` will always be `Optional`, its value being either `nil` in case `fubar` is `nil` or the value of `boo` wrapped in an `Optional` in case `fubar` wasn't `nil`.

Comment: `Optional<Bool>.none` and `Optional<Bool>.some` are little bit more visual here, easier to explain what's going on

Comment: Well that’s good to hear. What if I want to ensure that x is always non-optional?

Comment: What’s the exact meaning of Optional<Bool>.some ?

Comment: @user11787485 you have several optionals to unwrap optional values, one is optional binding. The [Optionals chapter of the Swift Book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) does give a good introduction to Optionals, you should have a read. `Optional<Bool>.some` isn't actually valid, `Optional<Bool>.some(true)` or `Optional<Bool>.some(false)` are `Bool` variables with a non-nil value wrapped in an `Optional`. `Optional` is just an `enum` with `some(Value)` and `none` cases.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, `Optional<Bool>.some` is valid expression, and has type `(Bool) -> Optional<Bool>`(or `(Bool) -> Bool?`). But, yeah I shouldn't've used it without actual values there.